# NetLogo agentset form links with other agentset

Tags: netlogo

I'm looking to have a turtle-set form links with other turtle-set.

My current attempt that also feels contrived, as not every hive here will be selected.Is there another way of going about this?

```
to link-bees-to-hives [bees-agentset hives-agentset]
  ask bees-agentset [
    create-link-with one-of hives-agentset
  ]
end
```

**How can I create links between two agentsets netlogo, in order of the turtles in the set?**

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by "in order of the turtles in the set"?

Comment: Agentsets are unordered. Every time you look at an agentset it's in a new, different random order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to have bees make a link with just one other hive? If you have relatively enough bees your attempt is probably fine, but if you want to weight the bee selection so that they preferentially link with hives with fewer associate bees, you could use some kind of `min-one-of` solution or a perhaps something from the `rnd` extension. For example, a bee and hive setup:

```
extensions [ rnd ]

breed [ bees bee ]
breed [ hives hive ]

to setup
  ca
  create-hives 3 [
    set color white
    set shape "box"
    set size 2
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
  ]
  create-bees 15 [
    set color yellow
    set shape "bug"
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
  ]

  reset-ticks
end
```

And the weighted selection:

```
to link-bee-to-hive
  ask bees [
    create-link-with rnd:weighted-one-of hives [ 1 - count my-links / count bees ]
  ]
  print [ count my-links ] of hives
end
```

Of course, if you have few enough bees and hives, you may still end up with a hive or two not getting linked-to.